# onActvityResult still broken?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have an issue where onActivityResult is not being called back in my fragment.

I am starting the activity from my ListFragment as so:

```
Intent getJobDetailIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),FullJobdetailLayoutActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(getJobDetailIntent,100);
```

Now I override and set a breakpoint in my fragments onActivityResult,

```
 @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    Log.d("ActivityResult FullJobDetailActivity: ", "Called");
}
```

This is never called in my fragment, onActivityResult is called in my Activity though:

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Even letting this call super as above, doesn't work...

I have seen some issues online:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15394

And read through a lot of questions on SO regarding this issue....

Does anyone know if it is still a bug?

I need to get data back from the activity started by my fragment!

Thanks all!

Comment: Works for me... Perhaps you didn't set the resultCode to RESULT_OK? But iI don't know how that would affect the problem.

Comment: *"Now I override and set a breakpoint in my fragments onActivityResult"* I don't understand what you're talking about, there is no `onActivityResult` on `Fragment` class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: In my ListFragment I override onActivityResult

Comment: [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) also doesn't implement `onActivityResult`, so you can't override it. If you post the relevant code, we can solve this faster...